# Override templates no effect - magento 2.0.1?

Tags: magento2, template

I try to override listing.phtml for the purpose of remove add to cart button from widget. I follow  [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-sample.html)

But no effects will be happen.I am using customize theme which extends to magento blank. The details are

**Default template path:**

`/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/listing.phtml`

**Customize template path to override default template:**

`/var/www/html/magento2/app/design/frontend/ChennaiBox/Style/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/listing.phtml`

In customize templates I am just remove one div tag(class="product details").

I am wondering why its not get reflect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run magento cache:clear?

Comment: Yes, I remove var folder as well as clear cache via admin

Comment: I can try from terminal also but no effect( bin/magento cache:clean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn on template hints is it using the template you think it is to render that listing?

Store > Configuration > Advanced > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

Comment: awesome idea to check.its my fault  actual path is "/var/www/html/magento2/app/design/frontend/ChennaiBox/Style/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml".

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 does not refresh content if files are residing in `pub/static` and coming from cached content. Please make sure to delete `pub/static` files and also running content deploy process once. This might solve your issue. You may delete below files from the project,

Delete `var/view_preprocessed, pub/static/frontend/theme/theme, var/cache/ , var/page_cache/, var/generation/` and then run below command,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

This should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer mode and back to production:

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
>
> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

then Magento will apply Your changes