# Overriding core phtml template using theme based inheritence Magento2

Tags: magento2

Could any one please tell how to override Magento2's core phtml templates from custom theme.

I have done as follows":

Copied

```
app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

To

```
app/design/frontend/MyModule/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Please help me further

How should the xml layout file be?

**UPDATED:**

I added as:

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

which is calling my phtml file..IS there no need of layout file?

Comment: If you only override the template file in a child-theme, you do not need the .xml file. This is nicely explained in the official documentation. Please see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-templates and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html

Comment: I updated the answer...if i do lke above, i dont need xml??

Comment: you done right no need xml file declaration for template override in theme level. I think you edit one phtml and check somewhere else. please enable the debug mode to check you edit the right phtml. refer this answer for what I am telling :-) http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106194/override-templates-no-effect-magento-2-0-1

Comment: I removed the the xml files under view/frontend/layout @Bilal...But my phtml file doesnt seems to be called from my theme folder..cleared all cache